# Publishing my FAT Jar to local sbt repo

Tags: scala, sbt

This is my build.sbt file

```
lazy val myproject = (project in file(".")).settings(
   name := "Slick3Test2",
   organization := "com.foo",
   version := "1.2",
   scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0"
   ),
   assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
      ShadeRule.rename("slick.**" -> "shaded.@1").inAll
   ),
   artifact in (Compile, assembly) := {
      val art = (artifact in (Compile, assembly)).value
      art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
   },
   addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly)
)
```

I published this locally using `sbt publish-local`

Now I referenced this is another project build.sbt

```
name := "Slick2Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
   "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "2.1.0",
   "com.foo" %% "Slick3Test2" % "1.2"
)
```

But I get an error

```
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.foo#Slick3Test2_2.11;1.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in '/Users/foo/.ivy2/local/com.foo/Slick3Test2_2.11/1.2/ivys/ivy.xml': bad module name: expected='Slick3Test2_2.11' found='slick3test2_2.11';
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.abhi:Slick3Test2_2.11:1.2 (/Users/foo/IdeaProjects/Slick2Test/build.sbt#L7-12)
[warn]        +- default:slick2test_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractProject' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractProject) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.foo#Slick3Test2_2.11;1.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in '/Users/foo/.ivy2/local/com.foo/Slick3Test2_2.11/1.2/ivys/ivy.xml': bad module name: expected='Slick3Test2_2.11' found='slick3test2_2.11';
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.foo#Slick3Test2_2.11;1.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descripto
```

Comment: According to maven naming conventions, artifactId should be in lower-case. Have you tried using `artifactName` different from `name` (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html), or make `name` lower-cased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your error has nothing to do with publishing FAT jar to your local repository!**

I believe the error is pretty descriptive itself:

```
com.foo#Slick3Test2_2.11;1.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in '/Users/foo/.ivy2/local/com.foo/Slick3Test2_2.11/1.2/ivys/ivy.xml': bad module name: expected='Slick3Test2_2.11' found='slick3test2_2.11';
```

Especially: `expected='Slick3Test2_2.11' found='slick3test2_2.11';`

That being said, your dependency should probably look like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   ...
   "com.foo" %% "slick3test2" % "1.2"
)
```

If you are not certain what is the `artifactID` of your library, you can always check it on your own, at:

```
${user.home}/.ivy2/local
```

Also keep in mind that `local` repository has precedence before `cache` and what is more, if some library version is found at you `local` cache, it will not be fetched from external servers.